# Spring MVC que hace la etiqueta <mvc:annotation-driven />

Tags: java, mvc, spring, spring-mvc

En una aplicación web Spring MVC en el archivo de configuración XML los ejemplos que he visto usan la etiqueta  quisiera saber de que me sirve la misma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este tag fue agregado en Spring 3 y configura soporte para las anotaciones `@NumberFormat`, `@DateTimeFormat` y `@Valid`, soporte para el [servicio de conversiones](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert), soporte para lectura y escritura de `XML` y soporte para `JSON` (dependiente de los paquetes presentes en el *classpath*).

[Documentación en ingles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config)